# What if a confidence interval starts at 1.0?

Tags: statistical-significance, confidence-interval

I am new to statistics so this might be an easy question. I know that if a confidence interval includes 1.0 then the result is not statistically significant because it includes the null. But, what if the confidence interval starts at 1.0? Like 95% CI: 1.0 - 1.9? Is that still statistically significant? It includes the null, but it doesn't cross it. Thanks!

Comment: A confidence interval containing $1$ (or any other values) doesn't automatically correspond to non-rejection of the null hypothesis. In what context are you using that rule? What null hypothesis are you testing? (It sounds like a variance ratio.)

Comment: @Dave primarily interpreting epidemiology study results where the null is 1.0. For example they gave an RR = 1.5 with a 95% CI: 1.0 - 1.9

Comment: @Dave Can you provide an example/source where the null would not be rejected? I know that 2 CIs can have some overlap, but you could still reject the null that the point estimates are the same, but I am not sure if the case you bring up makes sense to me.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov If the null hypothesis is $\theta=0$, then a confidence interval of $(1,1.9)$ would be fairly strong evidence against the null hypothesis.

Comment: @Dave I was thinking of an example where the CI includes the null hypothesis value but you would reject with a formal test, like in your first comment.

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov That is not what my comment says. If the confidence interval contains the hypothesized value, you don't reject (except that apparently there are exotic confidence intervals that do not correspond to inverting hypothesis tests). However, many tests, perhaps most tests, do not hypothesize a value of $1$. Probably the most common null hypothesis is $\theta=0$.

Comment: @Dave For epidemiology studies using risk ratio, hazard ratio, and odds ratio, the primary null hypothesis is θ = 1. That is the context my question is in. So the CI of 1.0 - 1.9 includes the null hypothesis but it is also the endpoint, so I'm not sure if this is considered statistically significant or not.

Answer (score 1):

It is incredibly unlikely that a confidence interval has the null value as an end point. But, let's assume that it did happen.  This would mean that the p value for your associated test would be equal to $\alpha$, the false positive rate.  In the case of a z test

$$ 0 = \bar{x} - z_{\alpha/2} \sigma/\sqrt{n} \implies z_{\alpha/2} = \bar{x}/\sigma/\sqrt{n} $$

and

$$ 2 \mathbf{\Phi}^{-1}(z_{\alpha/2}) = \alpha$$

by definition.  Here, $\mathbf{\Phi}^{-1}$ is the standard normal quantile function.  What the investigator would do at this point is not something I am prepared to discuss at the point.  Though I will say this:  If the CI you've been given (be it from software or otherwise) has only one digit of precision, ask for more.  I guarantee you that a CI which includes the null is likely due to rounding.

Comment: You assume the test statistic is continuous.  This often is not the case and there may be considerable probability (under the null) attached to an endpoint of a confidence interval.